# jquery.filedownloader not hitting the done or success callback

Tags: jquery, laravel

Im using the Snappy wrapper to generate PDF files in laravel (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy):

```
return \PDF::loadView( $view, $data )->download( 'Gender' );
```

Then downloading the file using the jquery plugin filedownloader (http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)

```
$(document).on('click','a#download-pdf', function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled').html('<img src="{!! secure_url("/img/ajax-loader.gif",[]) !!}"/>');
    $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'), {
        successCallback: function( url ) {
            $('#download-pdf').removeAttr('disabled').text('Download pdf');
        },
        failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
            $('#download-pdf').removeAttr('disabled').text('Download pdf');
           alert('PDF creation failed, please try again');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

I also tried:

```
$(document).on('click','a#download-pdf', function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled').html('<img src="{!! secure_url("/img/ajax-loader.gif",[]) !!}"/>');
    $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'))
        .done(function(){
                $('#download-pdf').removeAttr('disabled').text('Download pdf');
            })
        .fail(function(){ $('#download-pdf').removeAttr('disabled').text('Download pdf'); });
    return false;
});
```

The files are being successfully downloaded, so why are the callbacks not being hit?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your page is not blocking popup.
fileDownload uses iframe to pop out file.This will solve your problem.

Comment: the files are being downloaded successfully, the callbacks are not being hit

Comment: Yes but it uses cookie + iframe to make call back work. Check http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/                                                                                                 http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: I had face the same problem with fileDownload.js and solve this way

Comment: how do i check if the page is blocking popups?

Comment: For mozzilla write about:preferences#content  and Check block popup diabled.

Comment: Check link http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: ok, so i disabled popup blocking, and it the callbacks are still not being hit

Comment: ajax call response make use of cookie as                                                      For PHP, notice that this is how you send the cookie:

header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=1; path=/');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);